# Slide show on secondary screen

Tags: slideshows

I have two screens while presenting. Usually I present on the secondary screen (e.g. projector) and take notes on the primary screen.
In presentation mode, Mathematica automatically uses the primary screen.

How can I change it? Ideally, Mathematica would run the slide show on the screen were the window of Mathematica is placed.

Comment: When I change the env to slideshow and click top right button to toggle full screen it runs on the screen it was located on. Win10.

Comment: I tried this as well and indeed this is also valid for Win7. However, one needs to switch the slide show off fully and then move the window to the other screen. Then make it full screen and start the slide show again. When I tried it first one of above mentioned was certainly not fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

On windows platform one can simply change the secondary screen and make it primary (right click on desktop->resolution->choose monitor->tick the icon make primray). That will throw all icons etc. on the other screen. It is rather a work around. But nothing better was found (also not by customer support).